# Access site page without login Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am working on laravel 5.4 project.I want to access homepage without login.
Each time I hit base url it redirect me to login page.How can I access sites pages without login probably some kind of middleware there.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your routes, but yes, likely an issue with middleware. Make sure the route for your homepage or the controller handling it don't have an "auth" middleware applied.

Comment: how should i do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are using default auth in laravel than it will happen. Try a custom login system and modify it as much as you want.

Comment: Can you please add some details to the technical solution you present in your answer ?